# Python group by adjacent items in a list with same attributes

Tags: python, list

Please see the simplified example:

```
A=[(721,'a'),(765,'a'),(421,'a'),(422,'a'),(106,'b'),(784,'a'),(201,'a'),(206,'b'),(207,'b')]
```

I want group adjacent tuples with attribute 'a', every two pair wise and leave tuples with 'b' alone.

So the desired tuple would looks like:

```
 A=[[(721,'a'),(765,'a')],
    [(421,'a'),(422,'a')],
    [(106,'b')],
    [(784,'a'),(201,'a')],
    [(206,'b')],[(207,'b')]]
```

What I can do is to build two separated lists contains tuples with `a` and `b`.

Then pair tuples in `a`, and add back. But it seems not very efficient. Any faster and simple solutions?

Comment: can the list contains not adjacents 'a's?

Comment: No, should only contains adjacents.

Comment: I mean the input list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `a` items are *always* in pairs, a simple approach would be as follows.

Look at the first item - if it's an `a`, use it and the next item as a pair. Otherwise, just use the single item. Then 'jump' forward by 1 or 2, as appropriate:

```
A=[(721,'a'),(765,'a'),(421,'a'),(422,'a'),(106,'b'),(784,'a'),(201,'a'),(206,'b'),(207,'b')]

result = []
count = 0
while count <= len(A)-1:
    if A[count][1] == 'a':
        result.append([A[count], A[count+1]])
        count += 2
    else:
        result.append([A[count]])
        count += 1

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
A=[(721,'a'),(765,'a'),(421,'a'),(422,'a'),(106,'b'),(784,'a'),(201,'a'),(206,'b'),(207,'b')]
def split(s):
  return [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]

new_data = [i if isinstance(i, list) else [i] for i in list(itertools.chain(*[split(list(b)) if a == 'a' else list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(A, key=lambda x:x[-1])]))
```

Output:

```
[[(721, 'a'), (765, 'a')], [(421, 'a'), (422, 'a')], [(106, 'b')], [(784, 'a'), (201, 'a')], [(206, 'b')], [(207, 'b')]]
```

Comment: the question specifies "leave tuples with 'b' alone". Look closely at the example output- the last line is two separate lists of one tuple each. Your output combines these into one list.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use two lists. Edit: If the 'a' are not assumed to come always as pairs/adjacent

```
A = [(721,'a'),(765,'a'),(421,'a'),(422,'a'),(106,'b'),(784,'a'),(201,'a'),(206,'b'),(207,'b')]
new_list = []
i = 0
while i < len(A):
    if i == len(A)-1:
        new_list.append([A[i]])
        i+=1
    elif (A[i][1]==A[i+1][1]=='a') :
        new_list.append([A[i], A[i+1]])
        i += 2
    else:
        new_list.append([A[i]])
        i += 1
print(new_list)
```